# Lightsail and Letsencrypt - not rendering from htdocs folder

Tags: apache, bitnami, certbot

I have just tried to renew the ssl cert for my simple website running on a lightsail instance (bitnami), the renewal has failed and now my site is rendering from /var/www/html a default apache  page.

How do I get it to run from the htdocs folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

If you are now getting the default welcome page of Apache, it's because you installed the system's service and it's now up and running.

You need to stop and disable that service and start the Bitnami's one

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service apache2 disable
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start apache
```

If Apache can't be started, you will need to regenerate the SSL certs and configure them in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf file.

Comment: Wow - thank you that was so simple.  Could you point me in the direction of adding the SSL certs?  The process I was using last year down not appear to be working now.

Comment: If you already have valid SSL certificates, you will need to [replace the server.crt and server.key files](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/enable-https-ssl-apache/) in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf folder. If you want to generate Let's Encrypt certificates, just use [our bncert tool](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/understand-bncert/). You just need to run this command: `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool`